# Using SQL query with ASP.NET Core MVC controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core and in general the .NET Core Framework. This is my first "larger" application that I am creating with the ASP.NET Core & EF Core framework.

This application shall be a tool to list missing Building components (Transistors, ICs, Resistors, etc.) in our storage. The shelf in the storage has QR-Codes with fixed Values (code_a, code_b, etc.). Since the Buildingcomponents can be exchanged and thus have a different serialnumber, they need to be paired to the fixed Codes. These fixed Values are paired to a Component serialnumber in the Database table *componentRelation* (see image below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoEjl.png)). The Database used is the local one that was created alongside the project. My goal is to take the input *fixCodeInput* from a Create-form and use it to search through the table "componentRelation" for the fixed Value. When found, the code should get the paired serialnumber and create a new *BuildingComponent* Object with that serialnumber.

The problem is, that the code does not return the paired serialnumber. The result is always -1.

There are 2 models:

1. BuildingComponent
2. ComponentRelation

The `BuildingComponent` model defines the missing components with attributes: *id*, *serialnumber* and *insertDate* (When was the last one used = DateTime.Now).

The `ComponentRelation` model defines the fixCode <-> serialnumbers pairings in the componentRelation table.

I used scaffolding in Visual Studio to create the Controllers and Views for these models.

Key Info on my project:

- Context name: `versionthreecontext`
- IDE: Visual Studio
- Project name: `versionthree`

This is my `Create` function in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,componentSerialNumber,insertDate")] BuildingComponent buildingComponent, string fixCodeInput)
{
        //Create a new BuildingComponent object
        BuildingComponent bc = new BuildingComponent();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Set the insertDate attribute to current Date and Time
            bc.insertDate = DateTime.Now;
            string result = "Test";

            result = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"SELECT serialNumber FROM dbo.componentRelation WHERE fixCode = '{fixCodeInput}'").ToString();

            Console.WriteLine($"fixCodeInput: {fixCodeInput}, result: {result}");

            bc.componentSerialNumber = result;

            _context.Add(bc);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return View("Create");
        }

        return View("Create");
}
```

This is the `Create` form:

```
<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>BuildingComponent</h4>
<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">FixCode</label>
                <input type ="text" name="fixCodeInput" id="fixCodeInput" class="form-control" autofocus/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="add" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back</a>
</div>
```

`Appsettings.json`

Definition of the connection string

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "versionthreeContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=versionthreeContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

[Test data in the componentRelation Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoEjl.png)

Comment: ExecuteSql does not return database values, you should create an entity for componentRelation, and query that with LINQ.

Comment: Why SQL? Such sample can. be easily expressed. by LINQ.